# Export a specific file in project to maven local repository

Tags: maven, gruntjs, zip

I have a Grunt project which builds a zip in its build folder.
To distribute this zip, I have converted it into a Maven project and copied this zip into maven target folder.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>build</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>*.zip</include>
              </includes>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But this zip file is not copied to my local maven repository.
Is there a configuration or plugin which allows me to specify contents of maven repo folder?

**Updated**:
Structure of project:

```
myproject  
   |_ pom.xml  
   |_ build  
   |_ dist  
        |_ myproject.js
        |_ myproject.css
        |_ libs/
```

Directory I want to zip is: /build/dist/

The descriptor used:

```
<assembly>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>build/dist</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The resultant zip is as:

```
myproject-1.0.0.zip
 |_ build
      |_ dist
           |_ myproject.js
           |_ myproject.css
           |_ libs/
```

My requirement is:

```
myproject.zip
 |_ myproject.js
 |_ myproject.css
 |_ libs/
```

1. zip name = "myproject.zip" instead of "myproject-1.0.0.zip"
2. Go away with intermediate file structure build/dist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this zip file is not copied to my local maven repository.

The purpose of the Maven repository isn't to store single files, but the result of a build process (jar, war, pom).

If you want to build a zip which contains your program and some resources as a directory structure (logging-dir, tmp-dir, config-dir, ...), you can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) . Here is an [example](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-a-runnable-binary-distribution-with-maven-assembly-plugin/) .

**UPDATE 1**

Here's an example of my own. Take a look at the `<outputDirectory>` elements.

This is the assembly descriptor myAppDescriptor.xml:

```xml
<assembly>
    <id>myAppAssembly</id>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <baseDirectory>${project.build}/${artifactId}-${version}</baseDirectory>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <!-- Adds dependencies to assembly under lib directory -->
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <!--
           Adds startup scripts to the root directory of zip package. The startup
           scripts are located to src/main/scripts directory as stated by Maven
           conventions.
       -->
        <!-- adds jar package to the root directory of zip package -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*source*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.cmd</include>
            </includes>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/config</outputDirectory>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/log</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <outputDirectory>/log</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/sql</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/sql</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/mailing</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <outputDirectory>/mailing</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/tmp</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/tmp</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <grpoupId>com.enterprise</grpoupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyApp</name>
    <url>http://www.enterprise.com</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/myAppDescriptor.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.enterprise.MyApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>

                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- your dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

The zip has this structure:

```
Myapp.zip
    |__ config
    |__ lib
    |__ log
    |__ mailing
    |__ sql
    |__ tmp
    myApp-0.6.1.jar
    myApp.cmd
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Concerning your requirement of deploying the zip to the repository:

> Structure of project:
>
> ```
> myproject  
>   |_ pom.xml  
>   |_ build  
>        |_ dist  
>             |_ myproject.js
>             |_ myproject.css
>             |_ libs/
> ```

I'm not familar to JavaScript combined with Maven, but I think the project layout shall look similar to this:

```
myproject  
  |_ pom.xml
  |_ src
       |_ main
           |_ webapp
                *your js and css files here ???*
  |_ target  
       |_ ...
```

A directory named "build" is not recognized as a source directory by maven by default. The directory `target` is created during maven execution.

Another solution may be to configure the directory `build` as a source directory in your pom.xml within the `build` section:

```
<build>
    ...
    <sourceDirectory>build</sourceDirectory> 
    ...
</build>
```

Take a look at the [maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) , and combine these information with some researches concerning "maven and JavaScript".

Then it should be possible to produce a zip and deploy it to any repository by `mvn install` or `mvn deploy`.

Comment: Thanks @ulrich. Earlier, I was creating this zip using grunt task but looks like maven-assembly-plugin already does the same.
The folder I want to zip is `build/dist/*`. But using maven-assembly-plugin, the result zip has structure:
`myproject-1.0.0.zip/myproject-1.0.0/build/dist/*`

I want it to be `myproject.zip/*`. That is, I want to configure the name of zip as well as the directory structure. This is quite easily possible using grunt task. I was prefering if maven allows me to simply deploy a file(zip) directly to repo.

Comment: @lazyvab - you can control the directory structure of the assembly using the tags `<baseDirectory>`, `<includeBaseDirectory>` and `<fileSet>`

Comment: using includeBaseDirectory=false, I can get rid of just one level. That is, `myproject-1.0.0.zip/build/dist/*`.  
And by setting baseDirectory, increases directory levels instead of using new parent. I've posted my actual requirement and looking for help.

Comment: @lazyvab - I've updated my answer. I think you have to use the `<outputDirectory>` inside `<fileSet>`

Comment: actually my project is a library. So, 'src' directory is already present with some JS/CSS files. There is an aggregator grunt task that combines those JS/CSS files, does some compilation and finally builds a single JS and a single CSS file. I don't want to combine grunt build folder and maven build folder. So, /build and /target are meant to be different.

Comment: OK... did you try what happens if you use the `<sourceDirectory>build</sourceDirectory>` entry? (or build/dist)